# Loot lockout for Binding Coil of Bahamut?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

Yes, I know Binding Coil of Bahamut is extremely obsolete.  But there is one particular piece of gear that I'd like (specifically, the [Allagan Rod](http://ffxiv.gamerescape.com/wiki/Allagan_Rod)) from Turn 5 for RP purposes.  What I'm wondering is this: Am I only allowed to get loot from Turn 5 once in a given time period (I'd assume a week) similar to LFR in *World of Warcraft*?  Or can I keep running it and running it and still get loot?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the coils have had loot restrictions lifted as of patch 2.55. So you are free to spam Coil as much as you want to get your gear. (I'm trying to exact same thing for Dreadwyrm)

Also though if you want to save yourself some hassle you could just buy the Replica Allagan Rod if you aren't using it for actual combat, they are usually extremely cheap and plentiful over the marketboard.

Source: http://ffxiv.consolegameswiki.com/wiki/The_Final_Coil_of_Bahamut

Comment: Thanks.  I still need to level THM to 50 before I can use it anyway, and I like running old raids, so I'll probably (at least for now) actually try to get it off actual Coil.  Plus, I'd need to make a new RP armor set that would work for both THM and ROG once I get the rod (I'm currently using the ROG armor set from Lore tomestones), and I'd like to put that off until I can find an RP reason to do that.